# PHP getter/setter code completion in IDE

Tags: php, phpstorm, getter-setter

I see getter and setter code that has been implemented as a implicit de facto standard in our PHP apps, to the effect that every instance variable in the project classes might as well be public.

I don't want to see a list of getters and setters of every single instance variable in code every time I open a class. They're usually the first thing I see and usually the length of them surpasses the core content of the class which does something other than set and get, so I have to spend a minute scrolling like a muppet in a sea of getters and setters, especially when they are arranged like this:

```
$this->getter();
$this->setter();
$this->actualstuff();
$this->getter();
$this->setter();
$this->getter();
$this->getter();
$this->setter();
$this->actualstuff();
$this->getter();
$this->setter();
```

When I am on my death bed I will realize that half of my life will have been wasted looking at setters and getters, so I'm trying to appeal to my colleagues to not automatically generate them upon finishing instance variables out of habit and getting them pointlessly depended upon.

The issue here is that my colleagues like that they appear in the IDE (we use PHPstorm) code completion, which makes things easier when typing out.

I'm wondering if there is a technique to get getter code completion that doesn't use magic methods. A phpstorm plugin or PHP class perhaps.

```
class Product{
    private $price;
    private $amount;

    public function toGetter(){
        $return = array();
        $return['price'] = $this->price;
        $return['amount'] = $this->amount;
        $getter = new GetterObject($return); //Hypothetical solution class
        return $getter;
    }
}

$Product = new Product();
$Product->toGetter()->getPrice(); //appears in PHPstorm code completion
```

I'll take any other kind of suggestion.

Comment: Use `@method` and `__call` maybe? Magic -- yes, but you can describe all of them in advance in PHPDoc comment for class. As for your code example -- please provide code for `GetterObject` class.

Comment: GetterObject is hypothetical, its what I would like to be implemented.

Comment: And I'll check @method/__call out

Comment: As for mixing getters/setters with actual stuff -- use code re-arranging features (to sort class methods alphabetically while keeping getter and setter next to each other) -- `Settings | Code Style | PHP | Arrangement`. Together with custom folding regions you can hide all non-important stuff easily.

Comment: + 1 didnt know about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getters and setters are a necessary evil in the world of OOP. Yes, if a class is big enough it can be a pain to read through a list of getters and setters, but with the help of a well setup enviroment and or IDE, this does not have to get in the way of productivity and readability.

In the worst case, the actual boilerplate of getters and setters is so commonplace that it's easy to skim when reading and makes the code easier to reason about, if not boring.

In the best case, extending the class becomes child's play and remains easier to read. Most code, especially in larger code bases is Write Once, Read Many(, change infrequently) so the added time taken to implement the getters and setters is not something often repeated in a single class, and with the use of a well configured IDE such as Vim, or an IDE such as PHPStorm, this is a non-issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way of working nowadays (at least for domain code) is to leave the setter out completely (immutability) and generate "getters" as fluent-human-readable language expression [1].

### Configure PhpStorm

The idea is basically the same as in [Can IntelliJ generate getters without the "get" prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556659/can-intellij-generate-getters-without-the-get-prefix).

If you want to configure this for PhpStorm (2019.2):

Go to `Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates` optionally switch `Schema: Default` to `Schema: Project`

Than you can replace the `Code > PHP Getter Method` with the following Velocity Code Snippet:

```
/**
 * @return ${TYPE_HINT}
 */
public ${STATIC} function $NAME.substring(0,1).toLowerCase()$NAME.substring(1)()#if(${RETURN_TYPE}): ${RETURN_TYPE}#else#end
{
#if (${STATIC} == "static")
    return self::$${FIELD_NAME};
#else
    return $this->${FIELD_NAME};
#end
}
```

---

[1] V. Vernon, Implementing Domain-Driven Design, Addison-Wesley Professional, 2013, p. 246.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @tmhpfnr's answer, if you want to keep the `is` prefix for `boolean` types, you can use

```
public ${STATIC} function #if($GET_OR_IS.substring(0,2) == “is”)is${NAME}#{else}$NAME.substring(0,1).toLowerCase()$NAME.substring(1)#end ()#if(${RETURN_TYPE}): ${RETURN_TYPE}#else#end
{
#if (${STATIC} == “static”)
    return self::$${FIELD_NAME};
#else
    return $this->${FIELD_NAME};
#end
}
```