# Can IntelliJ generate getters without the "get" prefix?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, getter, getter-setter

IntelliJ has the cool feature to generate Java getters. For example, for a field `private final String foo`, it will generate a getter `getFoo()`.

Is there any way I can configure IntelliJ to generate getters in the format `String foo()`? I am working mainly with immutable objects and prefer this syntax.

Comment: Not sure if possible, but your desired syntax is against the [Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza these are known as "fluent accessors" and are used more are more these days. Lombok even supports generating accessors that way out of the box.

Comment: @BoristheSpider TIL. Sadly, I'm not sure if these accessors are supported by frameworks that depend on [Java Bean Naming Convention](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf?AuthParam=1414187327_12eeae19bd08754d7401009a406362da) like Spring or JSF or technology like Expression Language.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yeah, I know. Many frameworks are leaning towards field access rather than method naming conventions these days - especially with the advent of annotations. Depends what the OP is going with the beans. Incidentally, this is an attempt to make Java a little more conformant with the [Uniform Access Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle).

Comment: @Hbf, if you're using something like [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) for your value classes, you can generate your getters at compile time rather than with your IDE, and you can specify any method names you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neat question! Just to clarify @Danny Dan's answer since IntelliJ 15 has been released...

### To set this up:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>
- Select *Getter*
- Open the template configuration from *'...'* on the RHS
- Create a new template from the LHS - see example below
- *Ok* and select your new template

#### Example Template: `fluent-getter`

```
 public ##
 #if($field.modifierStatic)
   static ##
 #end
 $field.type ##
 ${field.name}() {
   return $field.name;
 }
```

### Why would you want to do this?

Checkout [Implementing Domain-Driven Design](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0321834577):

> The simple but effective approach to object design keeps the Value Object faithful to the Ubiquitous Language. The use of `getValuePercentage()` is a technical computer statement, but `valuePercentage()` is a fluent human-readable language expression.

Comment: this option is not available in clion?

Comment: I was struggling to find this, but eventually got there, creating a short video -- https://youtu.be/ln4b0LyFsF0

Answer (score 3):

If I understood right you cannot modify getters/setters in idea now. [Issue on youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-28206)

P.S. Ok, now Fix version is 14.1, from this version of idea you can create and choose getter/setter template directly in `Alt-Insert` menu.

Comment: added up to date info in the answer

Comment: 14.1 is in EAP, not fully released though.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some slightly improved templates based on @Ed .'s [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34899503/518179):

#### fluent-getter:

```
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
  static ##
#end
$field.type ##
${field.name}() {
return ##
#if (!$field.modifierStatic)
this.##
#else
  $classname.##
#end
$field.name;
}
```

#### fluent-setter:

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
  static ##
#end
void ##
${field.name}($field.type $paramName) {
#if ($field.name == $paramName)
  #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
  this.##
  #else
    $classname.##
  #end
#end
$field.name = $paramName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to have `isXxx` for `boolean` (for example `isConnected()`), if you need this then the template would be:

```
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#set($name = $StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project)))
#if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))is##
#else
  ##
#end
${name}() {
  return $field.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java Records in-place, Intellij has come up with in-built template for this purpose **Records style**

- Press Alt+Insert
- Select *Getter*
- Select *Records style* from Template drop down

[image]